# Find the condition that the line $lx+my+n=0$.

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

Find the condition that the line $lx+my+n=0$ should be a normal to the circle $x^2+y^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$.

My Attempt:
Equation of tangent to the circle $x^2+y^2++2gx+2fy+c=0$ at point $P(x_1,y_1)$ is:
$$xx_1+yy_1+g(x+x_1)+f(y+y_1)+c=0$$
Slope of tangent$=-\dfrac {x_1+g}{y_1+f}$
Since, tangent is perpendicular to Normal,
the slope of normal $=\dfrac {y_1+f}{x_1+g}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line is perpendicular to the circle iff it passes through its center. The circle's equation can be rewritten as $(x+g)^2+(y+f)^2=f^2+g^2-c$, which shows that $(-g, -f)$ is the center.

So the condition becomes $lg+mf=n$